# Drupal Module Block theme

Tags: templates, drupal, module, themes, block

I am new to Drupal theming. I have create a block module called "mymoduleblock",

here is a part of the code i put together.

```
function mymoduleblock_init() {
  $config = array(
    'type'       => 'external',
    'every_page' => TRUE
  );
}
function mymoduleblock_block_info() {
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['mymoduleblock'] = array(
        'info' => t('mymoduleblock'),
        'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
    );
    return $blocks;
}

function mymoduleblock_block_view($delta='') {  
 switch ($delta) {
     case 'mymoduleblock':
        $block['subject'] = t("here is title");
        $block['content'] = "here is content";        
        break;
 }  
        return $block; 
}
function mymoduleblock_theme() {
  return array(
    'specialtheme' => array(
        'variables' => array('node' => NULL),
        'template' => 'specialtheme',
     ),
  );
}
```

i tried use a different name for my template, because most likely the template will be shared with other blocks. However, it keeps giving me "block--mymoduleblock.tpl" as the default template. how can i use "specialteme" as my tpl and share with other modules.

here is code for the template

```
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> col-sm-4"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>

    <div>

            <?php print $content ?>
            <br><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function mymoduleblock_block_view($delta='') {  
 switch ($delta) {
  case 'mymoduleblock':
    $block['subject'] = t("here is title");
    $block['content'] = theme('specialtheme', $variables) // array with variables you want to send to your template        
    break;
 }  
    return $block; 
 }

function mymoduleblock_theme() {
 return array(
  'specialtheme' => array(
   'file' => 'your_template.tpl.php', // place your file in 'templates' folder of your module folder
   'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module_name') .'/templates'
  )
 );
}
```

Comment: I actually want put it into my theme template folder so some of my blocks can share the same template.

Comment: You can put the file where you want.., you can use than drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME') . '/templates/' as path

Comment: it give me undefined block, html_block_id error when i use the custom template.

Comment: Did you use the hook_block_info? Because I didn't mention it here but u have to use that too

Comment: I have hook_block_info in the block module, but just cannot pass all variables to the template. it gives me html_block_id undefined error all the time.

Comment: variables array should look like this $variables = array( 'param1' => 'xxx', 'param2' => 'yyy')... then in your template you can refer to them as $param1, $param2